# How to save my data from excel which auto generate gridview columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, excel, gridview

I know this might be a repeated question but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I am importing data from excel to gridview but how do I save the gridview data into database and the column from the gridview are auto generated.
The data is already reflected in the gridview how do i save it in the database?

It would be better if anyone can teach me how to insert directly from excel to database without using gridview as the medium.(tried using [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-import-data-from-Excel-to-SQL-Server-2008-using-ASPNet.aspx/) but kept telling me that the excel sheet does not exist).

code to bind grid view:

```
  string conStr = "";
    switch (Extension)
    {
        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"]
                     .ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"]
                      .ConnectionString;
            break;
    }
    conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
    OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
    OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

    //Get the name of First Sheet
    connExcel.Open();
    DataTable dtExcelSchema;
    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();


    connExcel.Close();

    //Read Data from First Sheet
    connExcel.Open();
    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
    oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
    oda.Fill(dt);
    connExcel.Close();

    //Bind Data to GridView

    GridView1.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Yes I am using code from aspsnippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently done this, but i only did it for fileType `Microsoft Office Excel Worksheet (.xlsx)` . At first you have to copy the excel file to your Application directory, Then you save the data to `DataTable` and finally bind it to `Gridview`.

Use these namespaces

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
```

Here is the method

```
private void Import_To_GridTest(string FilePath)
        {
            DataTable dt =new DataTable();

            try
            {
                string sSheetName = null;
                string sConnection = null;
                DataTable dtTablesList = default(DataTable);
                OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                OleDbConnection oleExcelConnection = default(OleDbConnection);
                sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
                sConnection = String.Format(sConnection, FilePath);
                oleExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
                oleExcelConnection.Open();
                dtTablesList = oleExcelConnection.GetSchema("Tables");
                if (dtTablesList.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    sSheetName = dtTablesList.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                }
                dtTablesList.Clear();
                dtTablesList.Dispose();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sSheetName))
                {
                    var oleExcelCommand = oleExcelConnection.CreateCommand();
                    oleExcelCommand.CommandText = "Select * From [" + sSheetName + "]";
                    oleExcelCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    oda.SelectCommand = oleExcelCommand;
                    oda.Fill(dt);
                    oleExcelConnection.Close();
                }

                oleExcelConnection.Close();

                gridview1.DataSource = dt;
                gridview1.DataBind();



            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "Unspecified Error Occured..!! <br>" + e.Message;
                divMsg.Attributes["class"] = "alert alert-danger";
                mainDiv.Visible = true;
                File.Delete(FilePath);

            }
        }
```

Finally the Submit button Click event

```
 protected void btnsubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fileUpload1.HasFiles)
            {
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string FolderPath = "Excels/"; // your path 
                string FilePath = Server.MapPath(FolderPath + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyhhmmss") + FileName);
                // copy and save the the excel
                fileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath);
                Import_To_GridTest(FilePath);
            }
        }
```

**Update** : For saving data to database Use [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) Class

```
private void SqlbulkCopy(DataTable dt)
        {

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Bulkcopy"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
                {
                    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                    {
                        //Set the database table name
                        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.leads";

                        //[OPTIONAL]: Map the DataTable columns with that of the database table

                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Currunt_Company", "CuCompany");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Currunt_Product", "CuProduct");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Quantity", "Quantity");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Unit_Price", "UnitPrice");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Total_Price", "TotalPrice");
                        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Contect_Person", "ContectPerson");

                        con.Open();
                        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: From your code how do i proceed to saving the data to my database?
I am able to display it already sorry i missed that when asking my question

Comment: when binding to `Gridview` pass the `Datatable` to the SqlbulkCopy method for saving into database

Comment: i gt this last question
`sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Currunt_Company", "CuCompany");`
for this part of the code  where does `currunt_company` and `CuCompany` come from?

Comment: @JustASimpleGuy those are my Example Columns,Since i have to map my `Dataset` Columns to my database columns, I forgot to remove when posting, in your case they may be not necessary,

Comment: oh not that i appreciate it and it is actually useful but which 1 is the database column `currunt_company` or `CuCompany`

Comment: `currunt_company` is datatable column  and `CuCompany` is Database column.